# Dynamic variable being ignored in where() clause

Tags: php, laravel

I have been scratching my head at this for the past 2 hours.

I have a bit of code that gets records within the last 24 hours.

Then, once I have them, I loop them and loop a sub collection and set a property called 'answer' to the relevant Answer records.

Have a look at the code and then I'll explain the issue:

```
$last24HrWalkarounds = Walkaround::where('driver_id', $request->user()->id)
    ->where('company_id', $company->id)
    ->where('started_at', '>', $formattedDate)
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->with(
        [
            'questionnaire' => function ($q) {
                $q->with(
                    [
                        'questions'
                    ]
                );
            }
        ]
    )
    ->get();
foreach ($last24HrWalkarounds as $walkaround) {
    foreach ($walkaround->questionnaire->questions as $question) {
        Log::info('Setting answer where QID: '.$question->id.' // WID: '.$walkaround->id);
        $question->answer = Answer::where('question_id', $question->id)->where('walkaround_id', $walkaround->id)->with('defects')->first();
    }
}
```

The problem is that all of the 'answer' properties in the questions are the same walkaround_id.

The Log::info is displaying the correct walkaround id so **$walkaround->id** is correct.

This makes it even more strange, if I hard code an ID of a different walkaround to the one always being returned, they are all set to the answer for that question for that hard coded walkaround ID.

Why is my where clause seeing the same id over and over again even though Log::info says otherwise?

Thanks

Comment: Q: Have you checked the logs to see the raw SQL being emitted?  Please add this to your post.

Comment: @FoggyDay Yes I have, I logged the ->toSql and ->allBindings already, they were fine